# how to read between two heading1 word with aspose

Tags: c#, aspose.words

how to read between two heading1 word with  aspose
sample:
 [image]

## Test H1 1

Test Paragraph Paragraph 1Test Paragraph Paragraph 1Test Paragraph Paragraph 1

## Test H1 2

Test Paragraph Paragraph 2Paragraph Paragraph 2Paragraph Paragraph 2Paragraph Paragraph 2Paragraph Paragraph 2

```
 var doc = new Document(_basePathFileWord);
            DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

        NodeCollection paragraphs = doc.FirstSection.Body.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Paragraph, true);
```

im use this code for the Heading1 Word file 
what read contents  between two heading1 aspose

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code example to extract the content based on style “Heading 1”. You can get the code of ExtractContent and GenerateDocument methods from [Github repository](https://github.com/aspose-words/Aspose.Words-for-.NET/blob/master/Examples/CSharp/Programming-Documents/Document/Common.cs).

```
public static void ExtractHeadingContent()
{
    Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "input.docx");
    int i = 1;
    DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
    NodeCollection nodes = doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Paragraph, true);
    foreach (Paragraph paragraph in doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Paragraph, true))
    {
        if (paragraph.ParagraphFormat.IsHeading == true && paragraph.ParagraphFormat.StyleName.Equals("Heading 1"))
        {
            Paragraph newPar = new Paragraph(doc);

            paragraph.ParentNode.InsertBefore(newPar, paragraph);
            builder.MoveTo(newPar);
            builder.StartBookmark("bm_extractcontents" + i);
            builder.EndBookmark("bm_extractcontents" + i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    builder.MoveToDocumentEnd();
    builder.StartBookmark("bm_extractcontents" + i);
    builder.EndBookmark("bm_extractcontents" + i);

    for (int bm = 1; bm < i; bm++)
    {
        BookmarkStart bookmarkStart = doc.Range.Bookmarks["bm_extractcontents" + bm].BookmarkStart;
        BookmarkStart bookmarkEnd = doc.Range.Bookmarks["bm_extractcontents" + (bm + 1)].BookmarkStart;
        ArrayList extractedNodes = Common.ExtractContent(bookmarkStart, bookmarkEnd, false);
        Document dstDoc = Common.GenerateDocument(doc, extractedNodes);
        dstDoc.Save(MyDir + bm + "_out.docx");
    }
}
```